# Finding right ASCII code for a symbol?

Tags: text, ascii

For a design I'm making I need to use a character similar to the "greater than" sign (>), only less wide. Like this:

[image: symbol]

However, I'm having difficulties finding such a symbol. Would I have to use a `.png` image for this or can I use a real text character?

Answer (score 1):

### CSS

```
<style>
i {
border: solid black;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
display: inline-block;
padding: 3px;
}

.right {
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
transform: rotate(135deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.up {
transform: rotate(-135deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
</style>
```

### HTML

```
<p>Right arrow: <i class="right"></i></p>
<p>Left arrow: <i class="left"></i></p>
<p>Up arrow: <i class="up"></i></p>
<p>Down arrow: <i class="down"></i></p>
```

### RESULT

[image]

Comment: Nice implementation, but it isn't ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you will use it.

"›"   - using keyboard: Alt+0155
or HTML: `&rsaquo;` 
More alternatives at https://codepoints.net/U+203A

Comment: its soooo tiny!